# How Oracle SAMPLE clause work?

Tags: database, oracle, sampling

My group is doing a data evaluation request from client. We planed to use SAMPLE clause to extract some rows randomly from a table in our Oracle 11g database. After some research, we found there are no detailed explanation about how this SAMPLE clause work (process, algorithm, random number generator). Oracle documentation only explains how to use it and syntax but not in detail. The most detailed explanation I found is below from Asktom.

https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=random-sample-20000824

> Think of it like this, we goto each row -- we generate a random number
>   between 0.00 and 1.00. If the number if 0.05 or less -- then the row
>   is output. If the number is above 0.05 we don't output it.
>
> It could very well turn out that due to randomness -- a sample 5% on a
>   small set will return 0 rows!!! We could generate a random number >
>   0.05 100 out of 100 time (not probable but possible)

I could understand statistic methodology behind it. But that is still too conceptually. I want to know how exactly that random number be generated or validation from some kind of official document.

Could anybody give me a more detailed explanation about the clause?

Thank you

Comment: I don't think a more detailed explanation exists in the public domain - you'd need to look at the Oracle source code to see exactly what it's doing. Anything else is going to be speculation. But it's an implementation detail, so I'm curious why it matters. Tom's description seems to explain everything you need to know to use it (and explains the warnings in the docs).

Comment: @AlexPoole Our client are professional on statistic. There is risk that they challenge the randomness of our sample in evaluation process and we can't validate the reliability of it with solid reference. If the only way to avoid this risk is to dig into source code we might have to write something alternatives with lower efficiency and that sucks.

Comment: I guess you could raise a service request with Oracle to get details or assurances or whatever, but not sure how far that will get you. If your client dosn't trust a major vendor like Oracle that seems a bit odd. But how far do you go writing your own - how do you verify dbms_random,  or Java's or any other tool's or the operating system [P]RNG? Maybe you can just ask your client if they're happy with sample. Good luck.

Comment: @AlexPoole thank you. We already switch to dbms_random.value. At least that package has a good documentation so we know how does it generate seed and document of SAMPLE give us nothing. For asking client, IDK, it is tricky like quantum state. Maybe they don't care until we ask them. Anyway, the question doesn't bother me now but I still thanks for who could answer it. Have a good one

Comment: Why don't you run some tests to determine how random the sample clause is in practice? Even the documentation can be incorrect (or out of date).